# django getting a value/variable name from a form field

Tags: django, forms, field, django-class-based-views

i'm new to django, i'm trying to make a class-based views where i can choose what model or form i want to use (or not using form), for example :

views.py :

```
class Foo(object):
    #some code here

    def get_query(self):
        if self.form.is_valid():
            return self.form.cleaned_data['field_name']

        return ''
```

lets say i got 2 forms :

form.py :

```
class Bar(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length = 200)
    content = forms.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

forms.py :

```
    class Baz(Bar):
        date = DateField()
```

from the views above i got get_query method where i take the value from a field name, but the problem is not all forms are same, Bar got 2 fields and Baz got 3 fields, maybe i want 100 fields(just maybe), im thinking of using loop, so is there any way to get all the value from the field? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is self.fields which is I think a dict(?) and contains all the Form fields and names and so on. For any detail how dynamically to extract fields of unknown big Form just take a look at the code in BaseForm._clean_fields to get general idea of how to access them.